# Displaying label of an action (e.g., Save, Cancel) in Visualforce

Tags: visualforce, metadata, label

I'm working on a global implementation project, and in building custom Visualforce pages I'd like to use the standard Salesforce labels for actions such as **Save** and **Cancel**. Does anyone know how I can reference the labels dynamically so that I can display the action labels in the user's language?

So far I've found the ability to reference [custom labels](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_variables_global_label.htm) and also [object or field labels](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_dynamic_vf_globals_objecttype.htm). But I haven't found a way to get the labels used by Salesforce for the standard buttons.

Answer (score 3):

You can either use $Label.Site to reference standard site labels.  Here's a list of the standard site variables: http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_variables_global_labelsite.htm

Or you can use the Action's label:

```
<apex:outputLabel value="{!$Action.Account.New.Label}" /> //shows the label for Account's "New record" action.
```

Here's a list of valid actions.  http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_variables_global_action_valid_values.htm

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, James. Unfortunately the idea is great but doesn't seem to be working for me. When I use that formula in my page, all I get is the text portion of the property name. For example, `{!$Action.Account.New.Label}` displays "$Action.Account.New" instead of the expected "New Account".

Comment: Here's [my code](http://pastebin.com/XQMs6ML7) and [a screenshot](http://screencast.com/t/rudd4iEd5M).

Comment: I'm getting the same thing as @MartyC. Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: Hey, @DanielHoechst, I just logged Case 10570601 with Salesforce Support to see whether I can get an explanation for the unexpected behavior.

Comment: Response from Salesforce Support: "I have checked that there is no standard function {!$Action.Account.New.Label} . you are using a wrong syntax."

Comment: Hey, everyone, a [known issue](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000T4XUAA0) has been logged for this problem. At this point you cannot dynamically get the label of a standard action for use with Visualforce.